# What is the general approach on Login/Register Forms Presentation

Tags: website-design, login

So I am not sure which option is better for the User, to have a Modal Open when the User clicks on a Login/Register Button on the Navbar or if an external Page is the better approach?

Because often I see redirects to other pages but I feel like the User Flow is better if he logs in right on the page where he needs permissions and can then instantly continue his work without getting redirected x times.

Answer (score 2):

You've answered your own question and performed your own UX analysis of what is best for the user.

You're right to say that bumping a user out of their current workflow, to perform and action, interrupts their current flow, even if they are finally redirected back to the page they were viewing, before choosing to login.

Things to consider on a pop-up or a small login box that doesn't impinge on the layout of the page, however if they can operate in an asynchronous manner, then you've achieve the aim of not interrupting the user and maintaining their focus in their use of the website.

All good UX thinking!